# change alignment input type html in php code

Tags: php, html

I'm using this code for a gallery (everything works fine). I just want the input type to align itself to the center of the page (now align everything to the left), but this attribute can not be inserted into the code because it gives me a lot of php errors. Do you have any suggestions? here is the code :

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset="'.CHARSET.'"');
            echo '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"><meta charset="'.CHARSET.'"><title></title></head><body>'.
            '<form  name="pf" action="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'" method="post">'.
            '<input type="password" name="pw" id="pw" autofocus>'.
            '<input type="submit" name="su" value="'.TEXT_LOGIN.'">'.
            '</form></body></html>';
            session_write_close();
            exit;
```

Comment: "this attribute can not be inserted into the code because it gives me a lot of php errors" ...this sounds a bit strange. Exactly what attribute did you add? What errors did you get? Adding an attribute to the HTML shouldn't result in PHP errors, unless you messed up the string syntax in the process.

Comment: P.S. Not sure what kind of attribute you're talking about, but this would almost certainly be better handled using CSS classes.